# Find an element based on a data-attribute value. Syntax issue

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I set data-attribute with following:

```
jQuery('.question').data('status', status_value); // status_value can be wrong or correct
```

Now I have two lines going one after another

```
jQuery('.question').data('status') // returns value wrong or correct, e.g. data-attribute 'status' exists and filled with value
jQuery(".question[status='wrong']") // returns undefined
```

Why the shortened syntax doesn't work?

My task is to get the element which has data-attribute value as "wrong"

Comment: why can't you people just dump the html in the question,why?

Comment: If it's a data attribute the selector should be: `$(".question[data-status='wrong']")` Although I don't see how anything would return 'not available'. Surely it should be `null` or `undefined`. More code would help a lot here, as @madalinivascu says.

Comment: Just FYI, dataSet and `data-*` attribute aren't mapped anymore once DOM is loaded. BUT i guess this has nothing to do with your question...

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: @madalin ivascu let's say 6-7

Answer (score 0):

jQuery(".question[data-status='wrong']") select all the elements that have the attribute set to wrong but in the code `jQuery('.question').data('status', status_value);` you are setting the data object of the dom node not the attribute, to set the attribute use `attr()`

`jQuery('.question').attr('data-status', status_value);`

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it didn't work. Please have a glance on my updated question, maybe more info can give you the clue.

Comment: the second syintax is a selector, you are selecting all elements that have the status attribute to wrong

Comment: Yes, exactly, and it doesn't selecting any element, while the element exist(it's checked by the first line).

Comment: what exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: I'm saying that the second line from my code should return element which has data-attribute "wrong" but it doesn't.

Comment: the second line selects the element by attribute ,when you change the value using data() you are changing only the property data not the attribute